# Second Spinner not receiving the proper info based on the first Spinner's selection

Tags: android, spinner, populate

I know there are about a million topics on this already, but hear me out.

The title says it all, when i select an item in spinner 1, spinner 2 gets a specific list of choices to pick from (which will then be used to show info). It's essentially a small contacts book.

****UPDATE*****
All fixed and working, and an EXTRA special thank you to user FishTruck for helping out(i.e making it work!)

```
package com.your.package.name;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Contact extends Activity{

        public Spinner spinner1, spinner2;
        public Button btnSubmit;//not needed yet

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

                setContentView(R.layout.contact);
                findViews();
                addItemsOnSpinner1();
                addItemsOnSpinner2(0);
        }

        private void findViews(){
                spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        }

        private void addItemsOnSpinner1() {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

                list.add("Please Select");
                list.add("Choice 1");
                list.add("choice 2");

                ArrayAdapter<String> name = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);  

                name.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

                spinner1.setAdapter(name);
                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
                                if(arg2>0)
                                addItemsOnSpinner2(arg2);
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                addItemsOnSpinner2(0);
                        }}
                );
        }

        private void addItemsOnSpinner2(int selectedIndex) {

                int positionTop = selectedIndex;

                if(positionTop==0){
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list.add("Please Select");
                        ArrayAdapter<String> name0 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                        name0.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner2.setAdapter(name0);
                }else if(positionTop==1){
                        List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list1.add("Please Select");
                        list1.add("item 1");
                        list1.add("item 2");
                        ArrayAdapter<String> name1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
                        name1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner2.setAdapter(name1);
                }else if(positionTop==2){
                        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                        list2.add("Please Select");
                        list2.add("item 3");
                        list2.add("item 4");
                        ArrayAdapter<String> name2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list2);
                        name2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                        spinner2.setAdapter(name2);
                }
        }

}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Look at my answer.I guess that would solve your issue inshallah.If it does mark it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes as the gentlemen before me said.

In order for the second spinner to get the correct index to set the list,

you need to populate it after the first spinner is clicked.

/* wrong answer deleted */

if this is my code i would change addItemsOnSpinner2() into:

```
private void addItemsOnSpinner2(int selectedIndex){
    int positionTop = selectedIndex;
    //rest is the same
    /* ... */
}
```

and again insert these into addItemsOnSpinner1():

```
spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) {
            if(arg2>0)
            addItemsOnSpinner2(arg2);
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            addItemsOnSpinner2(0);
        }}
    );
```

that is just how i would do it

i think many ways works here though

edit2:oh and edit the addItemsOnSpinner2() in onCreate() into addItemsOnSpinner2(0)

edit3:you need to call addItemsOnSpinner2() in onCreate(), otherwise your spinner is empty!

edit4:sorry guys, i made a huge mistake into thinking onItemClickListener could be applied here, shame on me :((

btw, if you want to keep the index (under situation like change of screen orientation or back to foreground ) , it needs more complicated work

but here is a much simpler method:

1.set a global static variable: int selectedIndex;

2.in onCreate, set selectedIndex to 0 if savedInstanceState is null

3.in onCreate, after savedInstanceState is nullcheckd, call addItemsOnSpinner2(selectedIndex)

4.in spinner1's listener, set selectedIndex to selected index.

not guarranteed to work on every machine though:(

Comment: Hi FishTruck, Thank you for the reply, i am trying this now, and i will let you know if it works or not. thank you!

Comment: hi, do you know any paste and share website. i could give you some suggestion by rearranging your code.edit:nvm i found pastebin :D

Comment: Hi again FishTruck, I must be making the changes incorrectly, as no matter what i try, the app still shows errors.

Comment: sorry my mistake, i thought onitemclicklistener could be used on spinners..the logic is the same but we have to use other listener :P

Comment: sorry dude, thanks to point out my ignorance,here is working code http://pastebin.com/Nz5LcfxV

Comment: FishTruck, You are fantastic. It worked like a charm. If it's okay with you i'd like to paste it up here, for others too see, it may help someone else stuck on this problem!

Comment: Also, if you have a paypal account, i'd really like to buy you a beer :)

Comment: of course, feel free to share, it is a very unpolished version though. And no need to thank me, this site helped me a lot.i mean a super lot! just glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the `addItemsOnSpinner2()` function when the first spinner item has got selected.

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
    long arg3) {
addItemsOnSpinner2();}
```

Comment: Hi Nezam, thank you for the quick reply, 

I did as you suggested, but now the second spinner is completely empty. 

Do i have to move the method addItemsOnSpinner2{ } as well? Or is that okay where it is?

Answer (score 0):

you are setting both spinner at the beginning of the code ( in onCreate). You should populate the second spinner after the spinner1 data is changed